# Have a different language for the admin interface than the site's default in Drupal

Tags: drupal, internationalization

Is there a way for the admin interface to always show up in English, when the site's default language is e.g. Spanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is a module for this, that was made for beer: [Admin language](http://drupal.org/project/admin_language).

Answer (score 0):

change language in your preprocessor of page in template.php depend on admin/*